# Indirect dependency - .NET2.0 - WMP.dll

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, visual-studio-2017

After installing Visual Studio 2017 RC, I have some code that cannot build. I have narrowed it down to WMP and .NET Framework 2 (it works under Framework 4)

The most basic test setup is 2 projects:

Project 1:

- Windows Forms App
- .NET Framework 2.0
- Namespace WMPClient
- Reference added to wmp.dll (have tried both system32 and syswow64)
- Added Windows Media Player to Form1.cs

Project 2:

- Class Library (.NET Framework)
- .NET Framework 2.0
- Namespace WMPLib
- Reference added to WMPClient

Both projects build.

When adding `using WMPClient;` to `Class1.cs` (project 2) the build fails:

13 error lines like `System.Windows.Forms, mscorlib, System`

`warning MSB3258: The primary reference "C:\WMPClient\bin\Debug\WMPClient.exe" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.`

1 error line like this:

`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WMPClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The same code does not work under VS2013 anymore either, but did before installing VS2017

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to set a specific target for System.Windows.Form Version 2.0.0.0?

Comment: Properties for every System-reference show "Runtime Version = v2.0.50727" - this goes for both projects

Answer (score 1):

it says your "WMPClient.exe" has a higher version 4.0 of .net framework. 
And by principle one cannot add higher version libraries or namespaces in a lower .NET version project. So, Either build "WMPClient.exe" with 2.0, or upgrade your Forms Project to 4.0

Comment: Both projects are set to Framework 2.0 in Properties/Application

csproj:
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: Any luck?  I'm facing the same type of problem moving from VS2017 to VS2019 (on a new machine).

Comment: On .NET framework v3.5 it doesn't work. I upgraded my app up to .NET framework v4.0 in project preferences and it worked for me.